# Programming a punch in a fighter using sprites and XNA

Tags: xna, 2d, sprite

Hey I'm currently making a 2D fighter a lot like the good old Mortal Kombats using XNA 4.0. Anyway, I'm currently trying to program a punch animation.

The player is in the Idle state and on pressing Left Control, the player should punch.

Now assume the player is facing the left of the screen. All my sprites are drawn facing the right. So when the player punches, the sprite is flipped and drawn.

Problem is, the animation makes it look like the player teleports to the right abruptly because it is aligning the left most part of the flipped punch frame with the left most part of his idle frame (that's what I think at least). I cannot seem to think of a way to fix this.

My code is quite big right now. If someone could identify a possible section of the problem, I'd be glad to post that code.

Comment: How are we supposed to know the areas of your code that you might need to check?

Comment: @BeRecursive I meant if you could identify something at a high-level. These games have a similar structure. Essentially, I'm drawing every frame the same way. Starting at a specified position, for a specified width and height. I've hard-coded the frame positions for every animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed that problem. Indeed the problem was the sprite sheet. The guy who designed it, did not center each image in each frame.

So then, he centered all the images, but the frames were of varying sizes. But that problem persisted.

After some debugging, I figured out what was happening. In the Idle frames, there was a 2-pixel space on either side of the character in those frames. In the Punch frames, there was a 23-pixel space on either side of the character in those frames.

My `Draw()` function was drawing each frame based on a 2D position Vector. This position Vector, specifies the top-left corner of each frame.

Now since the Idle frames and the Punch frames have differing pixel widths to the left of the characters in each frame, it looked like the character "teleported" when the player presses Punch.

Now my solution for this problem - make all the frame sizes the same! This solved my "teleportation" issue. I could'nt figure out any alternative solutions to this problem though.

Now there's one thing I don't understand. There are so many games where sprite sheets are made up of different frame sizes. How do they use them without this teleportation issue?!

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you could use this overload to Draw:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Rectangle, Nullable<Rectangle>, Color, Single, Vector2, SpriteEffects, Single)
```

From msdn: Adds a sprite to a batch of sprites for rendering using the specified texture, destination rectangle, source rectangle, color, rotation, origin, effects and layer.

So you can pass the origin of your sprite as its center, and it will rotate around the center, for instance. Just find the optimal origin for your rotation.

Comment: Okay so I hadn't thought about the origin parameter at all. So my current Draw call looks like `spriteBatch.Draw(textureImage, position, null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(frameSize.X / 2, frameSize.Y / 2), 1f, SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally, 0);` where `position` is a Vector2 holding the current position in the screen where the sprite is to be drawn. Is my calculation of the origin correct?

Comment: This should draw your textureImage with its CENTER on position.
I believe you want all your textures to flip around the same point, so you'll have to make sure all your sprites are using an equivalent origin.

Comment: But how would I calculate those origins for each sprite? Say `(currentFrame.X + frameSize.X)/2, (currentFrame.Y + frameSize.Y)/2`?

Comment: Is textureImage the full sprite sheet, or just one frame? If the former, you should be using `sourceRectangle` instead of `null`, where `sourceRectangle` describes the position and width/height of the current frame in your sheet. Now set the `origin` to be half this width/height, and the `position` to be the top left corner + `origin`. Or, if you like, start conceptually thinking of `position` as the center instead of top left (requires reworking how you define and change `position`, but I prefer it.

Comment: @A-Type `textureImage` is an entire sprite sheet. Okay so I am using a sourceRectangle (sorry about that code). And I recently found out that the guy who designed the sprite sheet for me did not center each image in each frame. Do you think that is causing the weird teleportation?

Comment: Probably so. Ask him to center them, or you will have to set the origin manually to a weird place.

Comment: @rOim Will do that. I'll post the results here after that's done. Thanks for helping, you guys!